# Stata output directly to Latex

Tags: tables, import, statistics

I am looking for a best, most universal option to transfer [stata](http://www.stata.com) output to latex (of any kind) i know esttab and things like this however what if i want to transfer something different (any type of output not only reg)? What is the most universal and efficient method to do that?

I am using Stata SE 11.2.

In general what i want to have a stata log in `.tex` format. For example i want to have a tex version of vif table.

Command:

```
. vif
```

Output:

```
Variable |      VIF      1/VIF  
---------+----------------------
   meals |      2.73    0.366965
     ell |      2.51    0.398325
    emer |      1.41    0.706805
---------+----------------------
Mean VIF |      2.22
```

Comment: Could you provide an example of **what** stata (which is a non-free, costly software) output? Have you looked at the documentation? I see at least two relevant bits: [Saving and printing output—log files](http://www.stata.com/manuals14/u15.pdf) and [translate](http://www.stata.com/manuals14/rtranslate.pdf#rtranslate).

Answer (score 2):

The most flexible tool for this I can think of is John Luke Gallup's `frmttable`:

> frmttable is a programmer's command that takes a Stata **matrix** of statistics and creates a fully-formatted Word or TeX table which can be written to a file.

I added the emphasis regarding matrices.

Here's a little example of a VIF table:

```
sysuse auto, clear
qui reg price mpg rep78 weight
estat vif
return list

mat A = `r(vif_1)', 1/`r(vif_1)' \ `r(vif_2)', 1/`r(vif_2)' \ `r(vif_3)', 1/`r(vif_3)'
mat B = A[1...,1]               // extract first column in order to compute mean
mat sm = J(rowsof(B),1,1)'*B    // sum of column elements
mat vifmean = sm/rowsof(B)      // compute VIF mean
mat A = A\ vifmean, .           // append A by vifmean
mat rownames A = `r(name_1)' `r(name_2)' `r(name_3)' "Mean VIF"
mat colnames A = VIF 1/VIF

frmttable using your-path/vifexample, statmat(A) sdec(2) varlabels tex fragment nocenter replace
```

This stores the following LaTeX output

```
\begin{tabular}{lcc}
\hline \noalign{\smallskip} & VIF & 1/VIF\\
\noalign{\smallskip}\hline \noalign{\smallskip}Mileage (mpg) & 2.91 & 0.34\\
Weight (lbs.) & 2.91 & 0.34\\
Repair Record 1978 & 1.22 & 0.82\\
Mean VIF & 2.34 & \\
\noalign{\smallskip}\hline\end{tabular}\\
```

in the file `your-path/vifexample.tex`. You can then input this file in your document, for instance in a table float:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{An example of a VIF table}

\input{your-path/vifexample.tex}

\end{table}
\end{document}
```

This produces the output

[image]

Edit: Extended LaTeX code in order to produce compilable example after @Bobyandbob's comment.

Edit 2: Split LaTeX code for clarification.

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Could you make your answer  compilable, starting with  with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`?

Comment: @Bobyandbob Thanks, I have edited my answer.